# I cant acces to static content of my HomePage inheritance from geb.Page

Tags: groovy, gradle, automation, testng, geb

I cant continue, I am newbie in geb automation, I was trying to access to a element within of a geb.page, but i am getting an error, I am using Intellij like ide, please could someone help me please? my class structure and error message are the next:

The `Page` class

```
import geb.Page

class HomePage extends Page{
    static url = "http://www.websitetest.com"

    static at={
        assert $("h1").text() == "Test website speed and performance"
    }

    static content ={
        loginLink { $("a", text: "login")}
    }   
}
```

The test

```
void test(){
    Browser.drive(){
        to HomePage
        loginLink.click()
    }
}
```

Log/Trace

```
 [TestNG] Running:
   C:\Users\name.lastname\.IdeaIC14\system\temp-testng-customsuite.xml

 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: loginLink for class: FirstTest
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at FirstTest$_test_closure1.doCall(FirstTest.groovy:14)
    at FirstTest$_test_closure1.doCall(FirstTest.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:701)
    at geb.Browser$drive$2.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:671)
    at geb.Browser$drive.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at FirstTest.test(FirstTest.groovy:12)

 ===============================================
 Custom suite
 Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
 ===============================================


 Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Interesting, this should work like you wrote it, but can you try explicitly writing `page.loginLink.click()` instead of what you have now?

Comment: I tried that but doesn't works, I tried for different ways but no, inclusive I did a NavigationModule but when I do this: 
static content = {
        navBcontent = {
        navBar {module NavigationModule}
        
    }
'module' cannot be resolved and also I cant use navBar in my script, really I did a lot of things but I dont understand what happen, maybe I need to add another library or maybe the setup of project is wrong.

Comment: lol I found the problem, the value of text is "Login" instead "login" thanks @cfrick

Answer (score 0):

You have to use keyword 'at' to fetch declarations from content block and let elements inside it be used. Try this one:

```
void test(){
Browser.drive(){
    to HomePage
    at HomePage
    loginLink.click()
    }
}
```